# Is there a find sql statement behind a view

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssms

Is there a find the actual sql statement behind a view. I am in sql management studio, i right clicked on the view and i dont see an option to reveal the sql behine the view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Views -> your view -> Script View As -> Create

you can also do

```
SELECT OBJECT_DEFINITION (OBJECT_ID(N'your view'));
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning you'll need to have access to do so. But this is the correct way to view the SQL statement.

Comment: This is for copying the view, yes?  (so it shows a lot of extraneous information used to create new views)  What if he just wants to see the actual sql statement behind the view -- isn't that the design option like @JeffN825 says?

Answer (score 3):

Right click the view and Design...

Answer (score 0):

In SSMS (assuming appropriate permissions) you should be able to right-click on the view and choose the "Script View as" option.

Answer (score 0):

And why would you have views that are not in source control as a script already? You should not be creating views except through scripts.